# c# Set transparency to area defined by polygon

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, transparency, polygon

I have a bitmap and I want to apply transparency to specific area defined by polygon. That's not the problem. The problem I'm currently facing is how to apply transparency to INVERTED area of polygon. I've tried using Bitmap.SetPixel() but that is ultra-slow. Here is my current Method that works with normal polygon:

```
public Bitmap Mask(Bitmap b, Point[] mask, bool invert)
    {
        Bitmap ret = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ret);
        g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255,255,255,255));
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, width, height);
        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        g.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), mask);

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve the problem of how to apply the transparency to the inverted area selection of the polygon? If you have, tell us what you have tried, and why you are stuck. Just asking for someone to completely figure out something for you shows little effort on your part and is less likely to get a response.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.

I've used `TextureBrush` with `Bitmap b as a texture` and drew polygon on transparent background which in the end creates inverted polygon effect.

```
Bitmap ret = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(ret);
g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0,255,255,255));
g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

if (!invert)
{
    g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, width, height);
    g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    g.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Transparent), mask);
}
else g.FillPolygon(new TextureBrush(b), mask);
return ret;
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did? As it stands both your question and answer lack enough explanation to be valuable to the community (usually that means the question is eventually closed).

Comment: @Verdolino I've used TextureBrush with Bitmap b as a texture and drew polygon on trasnparent background which in the end creates inverted polygon effect. I haven't added/changed anything besides that.

Comment: Alright I added that to your answer. In the future, you can edit your own answer and add the explanation yourself. Gave you +1 and welcome to SO!